# Only run ajax again if last is fully loaded and success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got a problem while scrolling down and load content into my page.
The ajax executions load too fast, so the second, third and so... does not get correct information from the first ajax call, which are loaded into the DOM.

How do I make it, so the script only run if last ajax call is done and a success.
It should skip every scrolling up and down until the last ajax call is done. And then the ajax is allow to be executed.
And then over and over again until there no more to load though ajax.

Here is my jQuery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $(window).scroll(function(){

          if  ($(window).scrollTop() <= $(".wrapper_ac").offset().top + $(".wrapper_ac").height()) {

            $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            var ajaxURLvalue = '../../modules/language_text_loading/load_content.php';
            var langID = 'x';
            var onID = 'x';
            var setLimit = 'x';
            var setIn = 'after';
            var theme = 'x';
            var setInWhere = 'x';
            var conID = 'x';

            loadInstant(ajaxURLvalue, langID, onID, setLimit, setIn, theme, setInWhere, conID);
            });
           }
    }); 

});
</script>
```

This is my function.

```
function loadInstant(ajaxURLvalue, langID, onID, setLimit, setIn, theme, setInWhere, conID) {     

    var temp_s = $(".ltlID:last").attr("id");
    var split_ltlID = temp_s.split(':');
    var ltlID = split_ltlID[0];
    var acContentBoxID = split_ltlID[1];

    var dataString = {
        action: 'load',
        last_ltlID: ltlID,
        //sharedID:acContentBoxID_sharedID,
        langID:langID,
        setInWhere: setInWhere,
        onID:onID,
        theme:theme,
        conID:conID
    };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxURLvalue,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){

                        $("#accordionContent"+acContentBoxID+":last").after(html);

        });    
};
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I would do is store the ajax function into a global variable like this:

```
   global_variable =     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxURLvalue,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){

                        $("#accordionContent"+acContentBoxID+":last").after(html);

        });
```

and before the ajax call check if the variable is tru like this:

```
if(global_variable){
   return false;
}
```

this will stop any ajax call to be called before the one running is over. I hope it helps you!

Comment: But shouldn't I set the global_variable before running the ajax to check it? cause right not I am getting a error: Can't find variable: global_variable

Comment: Yes the global variable is set outside of the function as var global_varible.

Comment: Im not sure that I understand. I have added your code, but for some reason it still just loading and loading, while scroll up and down

Comment: Did you post the If statement before the ajax call? Not under ?